# Buscar nome file enviado por json

Tags: php, html, json, formulário

Estou a usar uma ferramenta para fazer crop de uma imagem enviada pelo user. Quando é feito o crop, o ficheiro é guardado na pasta e envio a resposta por `json_encode`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que eu quero agarrar no "name_file" retornado por json, e guardar na BD quando estou a submeter o formulário. 
O meu form:

```
<form action="runewcode?runid=ew-assinaturas001" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
(...)

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div id="cropContainerEyecandy" style="height: 300px;"></div> <!-- ONDE É FEITO O CROP DA IMAGEM -->
</div>

(...)
</form>
```

Estou a tentar algo deste género para ir buscar o `name_file`:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name_file']))
{
     //GUARDA NAME_FILE NA BD
}
?>
```

Comment: Pode postar o código HTML do Form?

Comment: @Diogo já editei

Comment: Pelo que estou a ver o ficheiro "img_crop_to_file.php" é o que retorna a resposta do JSON. Porque nao guardar na base de dados nesse momento ?

Comment: @Diogo, só me interessa guardar quando crio o registo, a menos que meta numa tabela temporária.

Comment: @pc_oc, cadê o código javascript que faz o post da imagem?

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, você não precisa fazer um formulário com `enctype="multipart/form-data"` pois a imagem já foi publicada via ajax. Quando vocẽ fez o crop. O que você precisa é apenas publicar o caminho da imagem no banco.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas atende sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

//Exemplo
$json = '[{"status": "success","name_file": "imagemTal","url": "www.tttt.com.br/imagemTal"}]';

$jasondata =json_decode($json,true);

//Aqui você captura acessa um valor específico
echo $jasondata[0]['name_file']; exit;

echo "<pre>"; print_r($jasondata); exit;

  //  Resultado:    
  //  imagemTal


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

O teu formulário possui o atributo `multipart/form-data`, que só é usando quando se quer enviar/mover um ficheiro para o servidor. Este atributo só é válido para `inputs` do tipo `type="file"`, e para receber os valores desse input no lado do servidor, usa-se o `$_FILES`, em vez de `$_POST` que é usado para outros tipos.

Ainda assim estou meio confuso, visto que na imagem acima tu já tens a requisição feita, e até um retorno, só não entendi esta parte:

> *"Estou a tentar algo deste género para ir buscar o nome da imagem:"*

Mas respondendo àquilo que percebi ser o problema, uma vez que já tens a requisição feita, e precisas apenas de ler valor dos parâmetros nela contidos, tenho este exemplo, autoexplicativo.

## Exemplo:

```
<?php

// header("Content-Type: text/plain");
// Comentei o header para poder exibir a formatação dos echo's
$arr = array("status" => "success",
             "name_file" => "croppedImg_11647",
             "url" => "..\/publicfiles\/croppedImg_11647.png"
            );

echo "<h2>Codificar com \"json_encode()\"</h2>";            
$encode = json_encode($arr);            
echo $encode;

echo "<h2>Decodificar com \"json_encode()\"</h2>";
$decode = json_decode($encode);
echo "<p><strong>Saida (Objecto):</strong></p>";
var_dump($decode);

echo "<p><strong>Valores do objecto 1:</strong></p>";

echo $decode->status . "<br/>";
echo $decode->name_file . "<br/>";
echo $decode->url . "<br/>";

echo "<p><strong>Valores do objecto 1\":</strong></p>";
foreach($decode as $id=>$valor){
    echo "<b>{$id}</b> : " . $valor . "<br/>";        
}

echo "<p><strong>Converter os valores do objecto para uma array :</strong></p>";
foreach($decode as $id=>$valor){
    $array[$id] = $valor;
    // Ou da forma simplificada
    // $array = $valor;    
}

var_dump($array);

?>
```

Comment: não é bem este o meu problema. Eu tenho "inputs do tipo type="file"" porque tenho estes campos no formulário (não meti porque o formulário é muito grande). A tua resposta não vai de acordo com o que pretendo, porque eu quero ir buscar o name_file para guardar na BD

Comment: Então, remove as informações que estão a mais, e coloca a parte do `<form>..</form>`.

Answer (score 0):

Se você já tem uma saída em `json_encode()` significa que já houve um processamento de upload, não faz muito sentido recriar um formulário de upload para enviar a mesma coisa duas vezes. Agora o que faria sentido é capturar esta saída JSON no javascript e não no PHP, pois você já enviou o processamento da imagem no PHP e já tem a saída em JSON, concorda.

Caso você queira tratar dentro do PHP e salvar algum dados antes da saída em JSON, você precisa encontrar onde está essa saída `json_encode($array_saida)` pegar essa variável: `$array_saida`, e localizar a chave `$array_saida['name_file']` antes de passar para o encode e salvar os dados no banco.

Entretanto, acredito que talvez você esteja dentro de um formulário e queira carregar somente a referência e exibir esta imagem dentro de um formulário ou algo assim antes de executar a submissão de um formulário de salvamento, ainda assim, não deve haver `enctype="multipart/form-data"` neste formulário.

A maneira de capturar o seu JSON, é justamente pelo retorno do mesmo método ajax que fez o crop desta imagem e gerou essa saída JSON. Como desconheço seu método eu vou dar um exemplo de retorno, baseado nesta API: **https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper**

```
 $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
              method: "POST",
              data: formData,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              success: function (data) {
                    var e = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                      $('#sua_imagem').attr('src', e.url); 
                      $('#img').val(e.name_file); 
               },
              error: function () {
                      console.log('Ocorreu um erro no processo!');
              }
 });
```

E no seu formulário de HTML:

```
<form action="?salvar" method="post" name="salvamento">
  <img src="undefined.jpg" id="sua_imagem" width="180" height="180" border="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="img" name="imagem"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: eu não vou enviar a mesma coisa duas vezes. Eu faço o upload de uma imagem, faço o crop (idêntico a capa do facebook) e depois quero guardar o nome da imagem

Answer (score 0):

Em php, para pegar o nome de um arquivo enviado via post por formulário, use o seguinte:

```
$_FILES['name_do_input_file']['name'] //retorna o nome original do arquivo
$_FILES['name_do_input_file']['tmp_name'] // retorna o nome/destino do arquivo temporário que foi criado como upload no seu servidor
```

Para copiar o arquivo recém enviado, use:

```
copy($_FILES['name_do_input_file']['tmp_name'], "diretorio/subdiretorio/".$_FILES['name_do_input_file']['name'])
```

Neste exemplo do copy, você pode alterar $_FILES['name_do_input_file']['name'] para qualquer outro nome que deseje que o arquivo tenha, mas vai precisar tratar a extensão